# Save an object to a specific location in the json file

Tags: c#, json, xamarin.forms

Inside the application I create a `Json` file in which I insert some objects and save them in a file inside the device. When I save an object, I always insert it in the last position, using the string:

```
if (!File.Exists(MyFile))
   File.WriteAllText(MyFile, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object));
else
   File.AppendAllText(MyFile, JsonConvert.SerializeObject(object));
```

What I would like to be able to do is read the entire json file that is present inside the device and save in a certain location index. it's possible?

Comment: simply appending json to an existing json is almost guaranteed to break the json format.  You need to deserialize the json into a C# class, modify it, and the serialize it again, OR use the generic jobject to parse is and insert data before saving

Comment: do I have to create a list, delete the existing file and rewrite all the objects contained within the list?

Comment: I don't know anything about your data so I can't say whether or not you need to create a "list".  But generally you do need to load the entire json file in order to modify it.

Comment: Why exactly do you care about the position you are inserting it at? Expecting a specific piece of information to be located at a specific index in a list is IMHO a bad design choice, unless it's for performance reasons.

Comment: I insert objects inside the json file that have a DateTime property, and I would like them to be sorted by date, so that when the application has to read the file they will have an increasing date, from the oldest to the most recent date

Comment: in terms of performance better to use an OrderBy when reading?

Comment: if you are storing a large amount of data it would be much better to use SQLite instead of a json file.  If it's not a large amount, then just sorting it after you deserialize it should be trivial.